# MSSQL: How does HOLDLOCK work if row does not exists?

Tags: sql-server, multithreading, thread-safety, race-condition

I run this query:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.Foo WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) WHERE Col1 = @Col1 AND Col2 = @Col2)
...
```

And lets assume Col1 and Col2 are both NOT the primary key and the query does NOT match any rows:

Is a locked placed and on which entity? The table itself?

Comment: Do you have an index on either or both columns? The behavior will depend on indexing details.

Comment: @DanGuzman There is no index on Col1 and Col2 but there is a separate primary key column (auto increment) which is not used within the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like if there's no relevant index it will RangeS-U lock all the clustered index keys, or in the case of a heap it will take an exclusive table lock.  EG

```
use tempdb
go
drop table if exists Foo
go

create table Foo(id int primary key /*nonclustered*/, Col1 int, Col2 int);
go
with q as
(
select row_number() over (order by (select null)) i
from sys.messages 
)
insert into foo(id,Col1,Col2) 
select top 10 i, i*10, i* 5 
from q


begin transaction

declare @Col1 int = 15
declare @col2 int = 5

SELECT * FROM dbo.Foo WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) 
WHERE Col1 = @Col1 AND Col2 = @Col2

select *
from sys.dm_tran_locks
where request_session_id = @@spid 

rollback
```